# Position toggle list according to the page Boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here i don't know the technically what will call but will try to explain the scenario what i want to achieve. following is the image what i am facing issue

when page right boundary is not touching the list it is showing like this.

[image]

when i minimize the browser window from any side i want list should come in the visible area of the page it should change the position now it is clipping the list like this

[image]

Please help me how i will change the position of the list as its touching to the any boundary of page like top, left, right, bottom. using jquery or css

Answer (score 0):

Put your table inside a div and for div add css rule overflow:auto

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can achieve that things,
For that you have to use `Shuffle.js`

Please refer this [Link](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/bootstrap3-grid/)